# MP4 file embedded in Word doc won't play if doc is read-only

Tags: microsoft-word, read-only, embedded

My user manual has several 30-second videos showing the bits tricky to describe in words. All worked well until I made all manuals Read Only to stop users making notes on the Word documents. However, the embedded file's icon in the document has now become inert. It becomes responsive only when I remove the document's Read Only property.

It fails on Windows 10 Word 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2 (probably Word 2016 as well) and .mov files suffer the same fate.

I don't blame Windows Media Player because the button inside the Word document is inert, so Media Player is never asked to play the file.

If the document is editable it plays back my video whether the mp4 file is read only or editable.

Q1. Is this expected behaviour? (I can't find any documentation on the web)
Q2 Why is playback linked to the read-only property?
Q3 Is there a better solution?

I know this is not the 100% right place to post this, but I am hoping that forum readers may well have experienced the same problem themselves. Please suggest better places to take my problem...

I tried to upload a demo word file, but 3.6 MB was too large.